# Wordpress X Theme - Cloudflare Flexible SSL - Pingdom Speed Test No Longer Working?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, themes, cloudflare

I don't really know how to explain this. Spent the night optimizing my site (http://wildewebmarketing.com) and running multiple Pingdom Speed Tests as I changed things. I then activated Cloudflare with Flexible SSL. Website loads fine in a browser, but now I cannot use Pingdom Speed Test anymore for some reason. It accesses the site, never gets past https://wildewebmarketing.com and this displays in the screenshot it downloads:

[image: Just says "Your IP is..."]

Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your site isn't loading as your HTML contains references to HTTP assets instead of loading them over HTTPS.

My recommendation would be to install this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare-flexible-ssl/